# how to remove separator between Navigation bar and Status bar - iOS 6

Tags: ios, ios6, statusbar, navigationbar

I am giving the same background color for both Navigation bar and Status bar for ios 6 using my below code. But i don't know why i am getting 1 pixel of separator line as i have mentioned in my attached screenshot. Can you please help me how can i remove this line?

[image]

here is my code for App Delegate:

```
//For changing status bar background color
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(51/255.0) green:(51/255.0) blue:(51/255.0) alpha:1.0]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];

//For changing navigation bar background color
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(51/255.0) green:(51/255.0) blue:(51/255.0) alpha:1.0]];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(51/255.0) green:(51/255.0) blue:(51/255.0) alpha:1.0]];

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can't in ios6 update to you app in to ios7  that removed separator.

Comment: Thanks @Nitin In ios7, its working fine. Only getting problem in ios6. Is there any anyway to solve this problem.

Comment: this is ios6 native Feature i dont think we can remove separator.

Comment: make the colour of two similar.